# Looking to pause a thread using thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a mouse listener for mouse pressed and released. When the mouse is pressed I want to have a counter incrementing a variable, and when the mouse is released I want to decrement that variable. Right now, my code is working and does that but the increment is going too fast I wanted to slow it down because I am using these numbers for the coordinates in a game. I tried adding a Thread.sleep(100) but I was getting skewed outputs. It looked like multiple threads were going at once and I had numbers all over the place. Below is the sample code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.*;

public class Sample extends JFrame {
    private JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    int i = 0;
    boolean once = true;
    boolean on = true;

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Increase());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Decrease());

    public sample() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(jp);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                if (!once) //false
                {
                    t2.interrupt();
                }

                if (once) //true
                {
                    once = false;
                    t1.start();
                }
                else {
                    t1 = new Thread(new Increase());
                    t1.start();
                }
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                t1.interrupt();
                if (on) //true
                {
                    on = false;
                    t2.start();
                }
                else {
                    t2 = new Thread(new Decrease());
                    t2.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample();
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int num) {
        i = num;
    }

    class Increase implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            int num = getI();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    setI(++num);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
    class Decrease implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            int num = getI();
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    setI(--num);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `Thread`?  Also, threads are not re-entrant, that is, you can't restart them once they have exited

Comment: You could use  single Swing `Timer` and a delta value to achieve the same thing, safely

Comment: The code is working as you have written it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Without using seperate threads, i would be stuck in an infinite loop doing while(pressed) i++ and would not be able to exit when the mouse was released. If you have other suggestions on how to do that I would be open to changing my current strategy

Comment: @SpencerSprowls correct me if I am wrong, you want the numbers to increase when the mouse is pressed down, and to decrease when it is released?

Comment: @SpencerSprowls You're missing the point, either you want to increment or decrement the value.  A `Timer` will call you back at a regular interval.  Using a delta (value of change), you can effect the direction of `i`

Comment: @RishavKundu Yes that is what I want. It is doing that but every time the thread.sleep is being called it keeps the thread going. For example my output starts out 1,2,3 then when i release the mouse it continues increasing and decreasing 4,3,5,2,6,1,7,0

Comment: @MadProgrammer I also have this working with timers but was wondering if that was the best way to do it. I am using java.util.timer though not the swing one

Comment: @SpencerSprowls `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());` prints `false` even after interrupting. Odd.

Comment: @RishavKundu Yes Im not sure why its not getting interrupted after i call sleep. Without the sleep calls the methods work perfectly

Comment: @MadProgrammer What would you suggest would be the best way to have the counter stay at 0 until the mouse is pressed, then it starts going up and down when released

Comment: @SpencerSprowls I'd just not start the `Timer`/`Thread` until it is pressed

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nevermind, got it working. Set delta to zero to begin with then changed it to 1 once mouse pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably running into a race condition between the two threads, the fact that `i` isn't volatile also suggests that the threads may not be working with the same actual value as each other.

Threads are also non-reentrant, meaning that once the `run` method exists, they can not be restarted.

You could achieve the same result simply using a single `Thread` and a "delta" (or change) value.

The following example uses a Swing `Timer`, as it's simpler and allows me to update the UI safely, but the principle is the same.

[image: Counter]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;
        private int value = 0;
        private int delta = 1;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("0");
            add(label);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    delta *= -1;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    delta *= -1;
                }

            });

            timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setValue(getValue() + delta);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            label.setText(Integer.toString(value));
        }

    }

}
```

## Updated with dual "threads"

And just because I'm completely crazy, and it's nice to demonstrate the extra work load.  This example uses two `Thread`s.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Value {

        private JLabel label;
        private volatile int value = 0;

        private ManipulateRunner incrementRunner;
        private ManipulateRunner decrementRunner;

        private Thread incrementThread;
        private Thread decrementThread;

        public TestPane() {

            incrementRunner = new ManipulateRunner(this, 1);
            decrementRunner = new ManipulateRunner(this, -1);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("0");
            add(label);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                    decrementRunner.pause();
                    if (incrementThread == null) {
                        incrementThread = new Thread(incrementRunner);
                        incrementThread.start();
                    }

                    incrementRunner.resume();

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                    incrementRunner.pause();
                    if (decrementThread == null) {
                        decrementThread = new Thread(decrementRunner);
                        decrementThread.start();
                    }

                    decrementRunner.resume();

                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(final int value) {
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                this.value = value;
                label.setText(Integer.toString(value));
            } else {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setValue(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    public static interface Value {

        public int getValue();

        public void setValue(int value);
    }

    public static class ManipulateRunner implements Runnable {

        protected final Object pauseLock = new Object();
        private int delta;
        private AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        private AtomicBoolean stopped = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        private Value value;

        public ManipulateRunner(Value value, int delta) {
            this.delta = delta;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void pause() {

            if (!paused.get() && !stopped.get()) {

                paused.set(true);
                synchronized (pauseLock) {
                    pauseLock.notify();
                }

            }

        }

        public void resume() {

            if (paused.get() && !stopped.get()) {

                paused.set(false);
                synchronized (pauseLock) {
                    pauseLock.notify();
                }

            }

        }

        public void stop() {

            if (!stopped.get()) {

                stopped.set(true);
                synchronized (pauseLock) {
                    pauseLock.notify();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!stopped.get()) {

                while (!stopped.get() && paused.get()) {
                    synchronized (pauseLock) {
                        try {
                            pauseLock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!stopped.get()) {
                    value.setValue(value.getValue() + delta);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Personally, the solution which is the simplest and works, is the better solution, but that's me

Comment: Thank you this seems like a much better solution

Comment: @SpencerSprowls Yep, the solution which is the simplest and works is usually the better solution ;)